# Issue in upgrading Newtonsoft.Json 6.0 to 8.0 because of System.Net.Http.Formatting.dll

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, json.net, nuget, assembly-binding-redirect

I want to update the Newtonsoft.Json dll from version 6.0.0.0 to version 8.0.0.0. I also refer to System.Net.Http.Formatting.dll version 5.2.3.0. It is internally referring to Newtonsoft.Json dll version 6.0.0.0. 
[image]

Hence i'm getting below error:
System.IO.FileNotFoundException : Could not load file or assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Tried assembly binding and added below in app.config

```
<assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="8.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
</assemblyBinding>
```

Still facing same issue.

Comment: What version of .net framework are you targeting?

Comment: @BlackFrog : .Net Framework 4.7.1

Comment: Change your old version in binding redirects to: `oldVersion="0.0.0.0-8.0.0.0"`. After that change your build output verbosity in `Tools > Options > Projects and Solutions > Build and Run` to Detailed or Diagnostic to verify, why build is picking incorrect version.

Comment: Version 5.2.3 of that package hasn’t been updated since 2015. I will take a deeper look once I get to my desk.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the Nuget Gallery page, "`System.Net.Http.Formatting`" ([link](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Net.Http.Formatting.Extension/)) does not depend on "`Newtonsoft.JSON`". Please view the attached screenshot / link.

[image]

I would recommend re-installing packages to resolve the errors:

`Update-Package -reinstall -Project ProjectName`

Comment: I uninstalled System.Net.Http.Formatting 5.2.3.0 and installed 5.2.7.0. Newer version also has reference to Newtonsoft.Json dll version 6.0.0.0.

Comment: That's strange because it isn't listed as a dependency. I'm sure there must be something else referencing that. Perhaps, you can take a backup and try updating all NuGet packages with the following command:

> nuget install packages.config

Comment: You're looking at the wrong package "System.Net.Http.Formating.Extension" is NOT the same as "System.Net.Http.Formatting".

Comment: Downvoted because this isn't the package in the question.

Answer (score -1):

Looking at the picture you added, you have two Formatting dll. The 5.2.3 version wasn’t packaged correctly. It has a hard reference to version 6.0 of Newtonsoft.Json. Even the description of the package has misspelled word. I am suspecting the spec in the package is incorrect.

[image]

Comment: I uninstalled System.Net.Http.Formatting 5.2.3.0 and installed 5.2.7.0. Even that has reference to Newtonsoft.Json dll version 6.0.0.0

Comment: On a mobile device, I will look at it when I get in the office.

Comment: You're looking at the wrong package "System.Net.Http.Formating.Extension" is NOT the same as "System.Net.Http.Formatting".

Comment: Downvoted because this isn't the same package mentioned in the question.